# Having issues finding a command handler

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So I am trying to find a way to make a command handler for this code:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (!message.guild) return;
  if (message.content.startsWith(!handler))
  message.channel.send('Command')
});
```

Can someone help?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I want to make a command handler and have that as one of the commands, since I use that type of command often

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the command handler example provided by "An Idiots Guide"?

http://anidiots.guide/first-bot/a-basic-command-handler

Comment: @TylerBergerDid you follow the instructions carefully? If you need you can add me on Discord for any questions you have; Eton#4446

Answer (score 1):

https://discordjs.guide/#/command-handling/
provoides indepth explainations and code, for an customizable Command Handler

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is something like this:

```
client.on('message', message => {
if(!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX) return;
if(message.channel.type !== 'text') return;

if(message.content.startsWith(PREFIX + 'ping') {
    message.reply('Pong!');
}
})
```

Comment: I am not having problems with my command. Just making a command handler work with it

Comment: @TylerBerger That command you have isn't a command, and it won't work with any command handler. I recommend using the one I provided above or the one on an idiots guide.

Comment: It's not a command, it's a Command handler with a command.  @TylerBerger

Comment: what you mean??

Comment: The `client.on(...)` is a command handler, then `message.content.startsWIth(...)` is the actual command. Which means if you wanted to you could just copy that part and modify it to make another command.